# If $m$ is a solution to $Am^2 +Bm+C=0$ then prove $y=\exp(mx)$ is a solution to $Ay''+By'+C=0$ and thus prove $y=x\exp(mx)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

My calculations so far is that $y''=m^2\exp(mx)$ and $y'=m\exp(mx)$. Subbing this into the differential equation I get the first equation with $\exp(mx)$ as a factor. However I can't seem to get the second $y$ function to show it is a solution to the differential equation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINTS**

1. Plug $y = e^{mx}$ into $Ay'' + By' + Cy = 0$ to show that $e^{mx}$ is a solution of the ODE iff $Am^2 + Bm + C = 0$.
2. If $m$ is the *only* solution of that quadratic, it must have the form equivalent to $A(x-m)^2 = 0$, which implies a form for the ODE. In that case, $y_2 = xe^{mx}$ will indeed be the second solution, which you can verify by plugging it into the (new form of the) ODE directly.

**UPDATE**

If $m$ is the only solution, the equation must have been
$$
0 = A(x-m)^2 = Ax^2 - 2mAx + Am^2
$$
so the ODE must be
$$
Ay'' - 2mAy' + Ay = 0,
$$
and dividing by $A$ (which should be possible, since $A \ne 0$ by assumption), we get the ODE
$$
y'' - 2my' + y = 0.
$$
Certainly, as you already showed, $y_1 = e^{mx}$ is a solution. Can you see if $y_2 = xe^{mx}$ solves this one as well?

Comment: the furtherst i got from your point 2 was A(m e^(m x) (m x+2))+B(e^(m x) (m x+1))+C(x e^(m x)) = 0. I cant see how what forms an equation equivilant to A(x-m)^2=0?

Comment: @AlexdeTurris please see the update

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/l5qsifbw6vx7ydh/tut1.4.png?dl=0 this is the original question

Comment: @BigAl1992 it says exactly what i conjectured -- if $m$ is a *unique* (only) solution to the auxiliary equation, then $xe^{mx}$ is also a solution of the ODE.